# Sort order of related products not working in Magento 1.6

Tags: sorting, magento, product

I want Magento to sort my related products by the position value I'm giving them in the back-end. When I try to do that, nothing happens; the related products are still sorted by ID and not by position.

I checked the configuration Catalog & rarr; Article sort by & rarr; Position and it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3):

In Magento version 1.7.1 this bug has been fixed

```
$this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
        ->setPositionOrder()
        ->addStoreFilter()
    ;
```

Answer (score 2):

under Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related

```
function _prepareData
```

change from

```
    $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
        ->addStoreFilter()
    ;
```

to

```
    $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
        ->setOrder('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
        ->addStoreFilter()
    ;
```

seems like a bug

Comment: It is a bug - i first reported in version 1.6.0.0 back in november last year: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=12558

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in the Magento Backend Product Edit area of a CE 1.5.1.0, tab "Cross-sells". To fix this I had to use the code of Magento 1.8

```
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Crosssell.php b/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Crosssell.php                                                                           
index 2dd1611..813209e 100755                                                                                                                                                                                                                
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Crosssell.php                                                                                                                                                              
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Crosssell.php                                                                                                                                                              
@@ -95,20 +95,20 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Crosssell extends Mage_Admin
      */
     protected function _prepareCollection()
     {
+        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Product_Collection */
         $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')->useCrossSellLinks()
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->setProduct($this->_getProduct())
-            ->setPositionOrder()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
+
         if ($this->isReadonly()) {
             $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
             if (empty($productIds)) {
                 $productIds = array(0);
             }
-            $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
+            $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
         }
```