# Sort Magento related products by ASC sort order with NULLs last (or NULLs excluded)

Tags: magento

My Magento 1.6.2.0 installation currently sorts related products in ascending order by sort order (thanks to this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008076/magento-1-6-sort-order-of-related-products-not-working)). The answer detailed there works beautifully, however I prefer my products with a sort order value of NULL be listed last or completely excluded. I've played with addAttributeToSelect() but I have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best solution, but I added an if statement to my related.phtml file.

```
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        // add the if statement immediately after the foreach loop
        <?php if ( !is_null($_item->getPosition()) ): ?>
        . . . .
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```